# Page scrolling not working on asp.net after implement AM Chart

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, amcharts

In my ASP.Net project page scrolling not working after implement AM chart in google chrome.

I have test in Mozilla Firefox, and safari browser Page scrolling is working properly in In google chrome page down scroll working but page up scroll not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page Scroll not working because of Bootstrap CSS Conflict issue now page Scroll working properly